# Hide part of directive on boolean attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got a directive that shows an `<md-card>` but I want to make it more reusable throughout my app by showing a part (the icon) only if the directive's attribute `isUser` is `true`.

However it would seem as if the directory isn't getting the attribute from where I use it on my page... If I use `ng-hide` on `{{ isUser }}` it shows up, regardless of what sort of data I send to it. If I use `ng-show` it never displays:

```
<md-card md-colors="::{backgroundColor: '{{theme}}-primary-900'}">
    <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-media ng-show="{{isUser}}">
            <div class="md-media-sm card-media" layout md-colors="::{background: '{{theme}}-accent-700'}">
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="resources/img/profile_white_48.svg"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-card-title-media>
        <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">{{name}}</span>
            <span class="md-subhead description"><span class="lead orange">Sentinel Number: {{ ptsnumber }}</span></span>
        </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
</md-card>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("card", [])
        .directive("card", function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/CARD.TMPL.HTML',
                scope: {
                    name: '@',
                    theme: '@',
                    ptsnumber: '@',
                    isUser: '@'
                },
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.theme = $scope.theme || 'default';
                }
            }
        })
```

Usage:

```
<card ng-repeat="person in vm.persons | unique: 'PTSNumber'" 
                   name="{{person.Firstname}} {{person.Surname}}" theme="user" 
                   ptsnumber="{{ person.PTSNumber }}"
                   isUser="{{ true }}"
                   ng-click="vm.setUser(person.PTSNumber, person.Firstname, person.Surname, $event)"></card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know which angular version are you using, and this is not mentioned in your post, but all these parameters would be better to be defined as `<`.
This allows you to pass angular expressions.

Then remove all your interpolations, you don't need them.

```
<card ng-repeat="person in vm.persons | unique: 'PTSNumber'" 
                   name="person.Firstname + ' ' + person.Surname" theme="user" 
                   ptsnumber="person.PTSNumber"
                   is-user="true"
                   ng-click="vm.setUser(person.PTSNumber, person.Firstname, person.Surname, $event)"></card>
```

Then in your HTML you have an issue:

isUser should be is-user (already changed in the above code)

And in your ng-show remove the interpolation as well:

```
ng-show="isUser"
```

All of this should fix your issues.

I hope this helps